# Cannot create virtualenv in SnowLeopard (MacOS 10.6.8), Python2.7 – errors

Tags: python-2.7, osx-snow-leopard, virtualenv, pip

I need 'virtualenv' for my current django project. I could install it, and the requested directory
was created with some basic subdirectories (bin, include, lib), but it stops on error messages that just keep me guessing. So I am hoping someone here knows the problem, and can help?

Below is some -hopefully- helpful console text output.

Thanks a lot in advance! 
Lena

#### **Problem Description:**

Computer config: MacOS 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard), Python 2.7.

1) Creating the virtualenv:

```
Suesssauer:site-packages sss$ virtualenv --distribute /Users/sss/EclipseProjects/django-projects/DEV
New python executable in /Users/sss/EclipseProjects/django-projects/DEV/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/sss/.pydistutils.cfg file.

COMMENT: fyi – Contents of .pydistutils.cfg
  >> [install] 
  >> install_lib = /Library/Python/$py_version_short/site-packages )

Installing distribute........................................done.
Installing pip....
  Complete output from command /Users/sss/Ecli...DEV/bin/python -x 
  /Users/sss/Ecli...VEL/bin/easy_install         /Library/Python/2.7/...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz:
  /Users/sss/EclipseProjects/django-projects/DEV/bin/python: 
  can't open file '/Users/sss/EclipseProjects/django-projects/DEV/bin/easy_install': 
  [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

COMMENT: That's true, it is missing. But it cannot be my job to copy it there manually, no ?

---

```
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv", line 8, 
    in <module> load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1054, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 654, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1020, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/sss/Ecli...ork_DEVEL/bin/python -x /Users/sss/Ecli...VEL/
bin/easy_install   /Library/Python/2.7/...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz failed with 
error code 2
```

No idea, the file "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.1.tar.gz" does exist (if this is the one talked about)!

2) Question: Check installation of virtualenv – do I have to consider these warnings below?

Console output:

```
Suesssauer:site-packages sss$ pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-1.7.2.tar.gz (2.2Mb): 2.2Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
Installing virtualenv script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
Installing virtualenv-2.7 script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try “removing” your `.pydistutils.cfg` file, as requested, before you run `virtualenv`:

```
mv /Users/sss/.pydistutils.cfg /Users/sss/.pydistutils.cfg.old
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-virtualenv/dKZYWuMcI7Y/Z27XXKF5M4sJ

And I think the error code 2 is due to `easy_install` as well, not the `.tar.gz` file.

Comment: Hello, you are my heroine of the day:) The link does not work, but I just removed the .pydistutils.cfg file following your suggestion. I hadn't understood any request for removing that file, it said, check the paths _within_ the file ('Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/sss/.pydistutils.cfg file.
'). So I could install my environment successfully now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to your problem but I highly recommend you using virtualenv-burrito which is the usual virtualenv packaged with virtualenv-wrapper classes that make organizing your virtualenvs much much easier.

Virtualenv-burrtio: https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito